# org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify build listener

Tags: gradle, maven-3

When we build our application using gradle, it is throwing the exception below:

> org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify build listener.
>           at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)

and **Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**.

How to resolve this error to have clean build?